# Having difficulties with for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm new at matlab programming, and I'm having difficulties with for loop. So my problem is for ex solving this equation Y(x) =1/(x^3-2), x values between some numbers and increasing in a certain amount. The code which I wrote is;

```
x = 5:0.1:9;
for i = 1:length(x)
    y(i) = 1/(i^3-2);
    fprintf("%c     %c \n",x(i),y(i))
end
```

However values for Y(x) is wrong. Can anyone explain me this?

---

Comment: You are computing the values of y(x) at i, not at x. There is a difference between the loop index and the x value for that index.

Comment: But when I'm trying to compute y(x) at x, it says "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values." and can't print any value.

Comment: Change the line to this -> y(i) = 1/(x(i)^3-2); btw, you do not need for loop for this. You could directly calculate y by giving venctor x: y(i) = 1/(x^3-2), outside loop. And fprintf need file identifier, you probably need printf + x and y are float so not %c, you should use %f